# Why cant I fscanf() two different files and get input at the same time, inside a while condition?

Tags: c, file, text, scanf

what happens is it gets all the input from fp1 first and then gets input from fp2. Why is it that way? Can't you get input from 2 different file pointers at the same time inside a while statement?

```
/*checks if 2 text files are identical */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char buf1,buf2;
    int flag = 1;
    fp1 = fopen("textfile1.txt","r");
    fp2 = fopen("textfile2.txt","r");
    /* putting them inside a while statement causes a logical error? why */
    while(fscanf(fp1,"%c",&buf1) == 1 ||fscanf(fp2,"%c",&buf2) == 1)
    {
        printf("buf1: %c, buf2: %c\n",buf1,buf2);
        if(buf1 != buf2)
        {
            flag = 0;
            //break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
        printf("SAME");
    else
        printf("NOT SAME");
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You have to use threads or concurrent programming. You cannot do that in a sequential programming method like you are doing currently.

Comment: @askmish, I think you missed his actual problem. The solution does not require threads.

Comment: Yep OP made some edits in the question recently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your while statement is short circuiting. When using the OR (`||`) operator, if the first expression is true, the second doesn't not get executed.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with the OR (`||`) operator, maybe you actually need an AND (`&&`)?

Answer (score 5):

You used the `||` operator, so only one of the `fscanf` calls will be successful. This also means that only one of the `buf1`, `buf2` variables will have a valid value.

If you want to read from both files, use the `&&` operator instead:

```
while (fscanf(fp1,"%c",&buf1) == 1 && fscanf(fp2,"%c",&buf2) == 1)
```

Note that your code may consider the two files identical even if one is longer than the other. To prevent this you'd need to check that the two `fscanf` calls failed at the same time.

Comment: It should be mentioned that there would need to be a little more complexity added to the program to correctly handle the situation where the files are not the same size.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I just added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this

```
(fscanf(fp1,"%c",&buf1) == 1 ||fscanf(fp2,"%c",&buf2) == 1)
```

The above is an or statement. So if the first one succeeds the second wont be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

When this line is executed:

```
while(fscanf(fp1,"%c",&buf1) == 1 ||fscanf(fp2,"%c",&buf2) == 1)
```

if the left hand side subexpression of the `||` operator evaluates to true (fscanf from first file is OK), the other subexpression (`fscanf(fp2,"%c",&buf2) == 1`) will not execute at all, so you only read from first file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a logical OR operator:

```
 while(fscanf(fp1,"%c",&buf1) == 1 ||fscanf(fp2,"%c",&buf2) == 1)
```

your code becomes:

```
 while(fscanf(fp1,"%c",&buf1) ==1 )
```

Note you are reading a single character everytime using `fscanf()`, so always `fscanf()` will return 1 if successful and hence will never go to the second evaluation expression. So, until it finished reading the file `fp1` it will skip reading the second part. And once `fscanf()` starts failing for `fp1`, which will cause the first expression to evaluate to `false`, then it will start reading into `buf2` until `fp2` is completed.

So you use a logical AND operator:

```
 while( (fscanf(fp1,"%c",&buf1) == 1) && (fscanf(fp2,"%c",&buf2) == 1) )
```

Which ensure that both `buf1` and `buf2` are filled with proper values and only then the `while` loop will be processed.

NOTE: For your application, you can also consider using `fgetc()` instead of `fscanf()`.

Also consider adding `EOF` checking in the while loop, before processing `buf1` and `buf2`.